# NullPointerException reading from text

Tags: java

```
public static void wordCounter(String target,BufferedReader source) throws IOException {
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        while(source.readLine() != null ) {
            String row = source.readLine();
            String[] separated = row.split(" ");
            for (int i=0; i< separated.length;i++) {
                separated[i] = separated[i].replaceAll("=+-!?'\".,:;", "");
            }

            for (int i=0; i< separated.length;i++) {
                if ( map.containsKey(separated[i]) ) {
                    int k = (Integer) map.get(separated[i]);
                    map.put(separated[i], (k+1));
                }
                else {
                    map.put(separated[i], 1);
                }
            }
        }

        if (map.containsKey(target)) {
            System.out.println( "Target word:" + target +
                    "\nAppears: " + map.get(otsitavSona) + " times." );
        }
        else {
            System.out.println( "Target word not found in source." );
        }
    }
```

This is a method I created to read from source and map all different words and then return the number of occurances of a specified word. The problem is at the line `String[] separated = row.split(" ");` I get a NullPointerException. What causes this and how do I fix the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the original code, the first check in the while statement will pass always but the second time source.readLine() is called, it would have hit the end of the stream (consider the situation when there is one more line to read and after the while check it enters the loop). As per the documentation for BufferedReader.readLine(), it returns null when end of stream is reached, and that should be the reason for the NullPointerException.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, I understand now.

Answer (score 5):

Your `while` statement is not correct. You are reading two lines at every step, where first line is ignored at while statement. At the end of file, second line is `null`, which throw `NullPointerException`. `while` statement should be like

```
 String row;
 while((row=source.readLine()) != null ) {
  //String row = source.readLine(); -> Remove this line.
  String[] separated = row.split(" ");
  ...
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to

```
String row = source.readLine();
while(row != null ) {
             ...
             ...
             row = source.readLine(); //last line of loop
}
```

Problem with your approach is that you are reading line twice first in `while()` and other is the first line of while which causes `row=null`  causing exception in `row.split(" ")` line

Answer (score 1):

Just as I posted this, I thought maybe it would help if I declared `String row;` before the while loop and used `while ( (row = source.readLine()) != null )`. Everything works now. What causes the NullPointerException in my original attempt?

Comment: In your original post you are reading two lines and check only if the first line is null in each iteration

Answer (score 0):

`while` loop should be as follows,

```
String row="";
 while((row=source.readLine()) != null ) {
  //....
 }
```